# How can PHP talk to a C# process running on mono?

Tags: c#, php, mono

I am coding a web application in PHP and it has some performance intensive parts that I'd like to rewrite in a compiled language. I know that I could probably get this done more easily just by writing a C++ extension for PHP, but I'm a bit too spoiled by managed languages like C#, so I'd like to avoid C++ if possible.

If I wanted a PHP script to execute a function inside of a running C# (on mono) process, how could I do this? My first guess is to have PHP open a socket to the C# process, do the work, and close the socket, but I think that would add unnecessary overhead.

Are [named pipes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.posix-mkfifo.php) something that could solve this problem? If so, do they work on windows (my development machine), and how do I use them from C#?

If not, what other options do I have?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you considered using the PHP.NET compiler, [Phalanger](http://www.php-compiler.net/)?

- [Runs some very well-known PHP applications](http://www.php-compiler.net/doku.php?id=apps), including:

  - MediaWiki
  - PhpMyAdmin
  - PhpBB 2 & 3
- [Works under Mono](http://www.php-compiler.net/doku.php?id=core:phalanger_for_mono_users)
- [Performs substantially better than PHP 4.3.7 on Apache](http://www.willydev.net/descargas/willydev_compilingphp.pdf) (PDF: see benchmark at end)
- [Call .NET libraries (including your own) from PHP](http://www.php-compiler.net/lib/exe/fetch.php?id=documentation&cache=cache&media=integrating_php_with_clr.pdf) (PDF)
- [Call PHP from other .NET languages](http://www.php-compiler.net/doku.php?id=interop-with-other-languages)
- [PHP/CLR Language Extensions](http://www.php-compiler.net/lib/exe/fetch.php?id=documentation&cache=cache&media=php-clr_phalanger_language_extensions.pdf) (PDF) make it a First Class .NET Language

Comment: +1: I read about a company that used this to convert several thousand php files and over 2 million lines of code into 3 .NET assemblies in .net magazine xD. Much more portable, and faster. There is now an almost 1-to-1 conversion match between php and C# and you can communicate between php and .NET

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to write a PHP module that embeds the Mono runtime in your application.

Here is the documentation on embedding the Mono runtime in your application, in this case, it would be PHP:

http://mono-project.com/Embedding_Mono

Answer (score 0):

There was a [PECL extension for mono](http://pecl.php.net/package/mono), but it's no longer maintained (last version was in 2003) ; so, this one is probably bad idea on the long term...

For something more recent, searching the php's documentation, if you want to work with .NET, you might be interested by [COM and .Net (Windows)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.com.php) ; but it probably won't be OK for you, as you specify "mono", which probably means "non-windows" platform :-(

Every time I've heard about extending PHP with a compiled langage, it was using C (and, sometimes, C++) ; I've never about using C#/.NET/mono for that...

... So, you might not find what you are looking for :-(

Like you said, with multi-processes, and communication between those, you could do something... But not sure it's such a good idea...

*(Compiling PHP to .NET seems possible, though -- but it's like the exact opposite of what you're asking ^^ )*

Comment: Actually, using Phalanger (PHP.NET) would allow C# or Managed-C++ to be called directly from PHP (and vice-versa), with almost no overhead.